# Problem to upload a file from local to Azure Blob Storage in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I try to upload a simple file to azure blob storage with the below code.
When I run first-time "mu_blob" created but `samplesource.txt` didn't upload.
When run second-time I received this error and the file didn't upload.

```
ErrorCode:BlobAlreadyExists
Error:None

from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="*****", container_name="test", blob_name="my_blob")

with open("./SampleSource.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

[image]

Comment: upload_blob has a parameter if you want to overwrite or not

Comment: @ChristianSloper My problem is the SampleSource.txt didn't upload on the blob.

Comment: note that samplesource is not uploaeded.. it uploads to a blob called "my_blob"

Comment: @ChristianSloper I know but it's empty. I added a screenshot.

Comment: add overwrite=True, and blob_type='BlockBlob' ?

Comment: @MohsenAkhavan, please make sure the source file(SampleSource.txt) is not empty. and which version of the sdk are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is probably because you are creating blob with different name than `SampleSource.txt`.* Check out below code sample to understand uploading of blob better:

```
# Create a local directory to hold blob data
local_path = "./data"
os.mkdir(local_path)

# Create a file in the local data directory to upload and download
local_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

# Write text to the file
file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
file.write("Hello, World!")
file.close()

# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

# Upload the created file
with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

I would further suggest you to go through [Quickstart: Manage blobs with Python v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python).

Comment: I had this issue and my solution as to use "from_connection_string" vs. other connection methods.  The person who submitted the original question should check that their connection string is correct and also check that it's from the correct storage account.